# Time complexity to find all pairs in an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of numbers, find all unique pairs.

For example, given [ 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6] the unique number pairs would be 1, 2 and 4 (each appearing twice, where as the value 3 appears 3 times, 6 appears as 2 pairs and is thus not unique, 4 and 5 only once).

Are there any better solutions than O(n)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pair" - it looks like you're just filtering for the numbers that occur an even number of times. Edit: okay, you mean numbers that appear exactly twice?

Comment: You have to iterate once through each term in your list, there's no possible way you can achieve under O(n).

Comment: How are 1, 2, and 4 "pairs?"  A pair is two things. These are 3 instances of one thing. I'm confused :-P

Answer (score 2):

*In the given form*, the best you can do is **O(n)**.  Information theory makes this accessible.  The argument boils down to the fact that, with no meta-information about the sequence, you *must* access each individual item.  This trivially sets **O(n)** as a lower bound.

If you have some existing descriptive data, such as a pre-existing count of each value, or something about the positioning or distribution within the list, there *might* be a way to reduce the complexity.

For instance, *without* the `5`, this list has the property that the first occurrences of the values are in frequency order:

```
number freq
  1      2
  4      2
  2      2
  3      3
  6      4
```

You could obviously harness this to improve the average case; one or two other restrictions could make it work for worst (acceptable) case, as well.